# How to output an RMarkdown file (which is run with params) within a Shiny tab

Tags: shiny, r-markdown

I would like to display an RMarkdown file within a Shiny tab. The problem is that it works only if there are no params explicitly passed to RMarkdown file. The enclosed files correspond to a Shiny app which has 2 tabs: one with a download button (which works as intended), and one which is showing the output of the RMarkdown report (but without params)

Would you know how this can be done?

Next there are 2 files embedded. The data file is the common iris.csv.

The shiny app code (shinyMinimal.R):

```
library(rmarkdown)
library(shiny)

thisUI <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Report in webpage",
           includeMarkdown("minimalReport.Rmd")
        ),
        tabPanel("Download report",
          flowLayout(
            radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('HTML', 'Word', 'PDF'),inline = TRUE
           ),
        downloadButton(outputId = "downloadReport", label  = "Download the report")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
thisServer <-  function(input, output) {
   output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
     filename = function() {
       switch(
         input$format, 
         PDF =  base::paste('minimalReport', sep = '.','pdf'), 
         HTML = base::paste('minimalReport', sep = '.','html'),
         Word = base::paste('minimalReport', sep = '.','docx')
       )
    },
    content = function(nameOutputFile) {
      nameInputThisFile <- "iris.csv"
      paramsReportTwo <- list(n = 64, nameInputFile = nameInputThisFile)
      inputRmdFile <- "minimalReport.Rmd"

      rmarkdown::render(input = inputRmdFile,
                    params = paramsReportTwo,
                    output_file = nameOutputFile,
                    switch(input$format,
                           PDF = pdf_document(), 
                           HTML = html_document(), 
                           Word = word_document()
                    )
      )
     }
    )  
  }

 shiny::shinyApp(ui = thisUI, server = thisServer)
```

The second is the RMarkdown report (minimalReport.R)

````
---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: html_document
params:
  n: NA
  nameInputFile: NA
---

There is some text.

```{r}
# The `params` object is available in the document.
params$n
```

A plot of `r params$n` random points.

```{r}
plot(rnorm(params$n), rnorm(params$n))
```
Read from a file
```{r}
inputData <- readr::read_csv(params$nameInputFile)
```
The mean of first data column from file `r params$nameInputFile` is `r mean(inputData[[1]])`

And then show a table
```{r}
head(inputData)
```
The End
````